# Calculated Field Within a Query in Access 2016

Tags: ms-access

I realize that this question is quite basic. And I have found various answers on various other forums - all of which use SQL which for the purpose of this assignment (it is for school) I cannot use. I have to physically type the answer into the Field box.

The question reads as such: "Add a calculated field in the third column. Name the field ExtendedAmount. This field should multiply the quantity ordered (from the Order Details table) by the unit price for that item (from the Products table). This will calculate the total amount for each order. Format the calculated field as Currency and change the caption to Total Dollars. Change the Total row to Sum."

I have attached a screenshot of what I tried, in Design View, as well as the relationships of the tables required for the question and other parts of the query. When I click "Run" that is where I hit a snag - it provides and other box which says, "Enter Parameter Value" which as I understand it should be supplied by the Order Details Table.

Does anyone have any idea as to what I can do to fix this? Here is the expression I built as well --- ExtendedAmount: ([QuantityOrdered]*[UnitPrice])

Thanks,
Josh

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The quantity field is called `[Quantity]`, not `[QuantityOrdered]`. Adjust your expression accordingly.